# Run Jenkins in a Docker container fails with script.sh: docker: not found

Tags: docker, jenkins

I tried to build a simple JS app in Jenkins Docker container locally and the build failed with:

```
script.sh: docker: not found (full stack trace is omitted for easier reading)
```

Here is `Jenkinsfile` of the app:

```
pipeline {
  agent { dockerfile true }

  stages {
    stage('Install') {
      steps {
        sh 'node -v '      
        sh 'yarn -v'
        sh 'ember -v'

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is `Dockerfile` of the app:

```
FROM node:12

RUN curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
RUN npm install -g ember-cli
```

What am I missing? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the docker client on your Jenkins nodes.

If you're running Jenkins as docker container, you have to install Docker inside it as well.

This Dockerfile will use a Jenkins container as a base image and then install the docker client , So that it can communicate with the docker daemon.

from jenkinsci/jenkins:lts

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -qqy apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg2 software-properties-common 
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -
RUN add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
RUN apt-get update  -qq \
    && apt-get install docker-ce=17.12.1~ce-0~debian -y
RUN usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Or if you're installing Jenkins in another way, you still have to install Docker on Jenkins node.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I installed Docker plugin from the Jenkins interface (`Manage Jenkins - Manage Plugins`. Isn't it enough?

Comment: Even after adding your code snippet to the Dockerfile, I'm getting `script.sh: docker: not found`. I specified `agent { dockerfile true }` in the Jenkinsfile `pipeline` section.